# Cordova version not change

Tags: cordova

I would like to update the version of Cordova within my project.
If I run

```
npm info cordova
```

it return:

```
cordova@9.0.0 | Apache-2.0 | deps: 8 | versions: 1222
```

if instead I run the command:

```
cordova -v
```

It gives me 7.0.1.

How can I update or use "global" version of cordova?
I tried to use:

```
 npm uninstall cordova
 npm install cordova@9.0.0 --save
 npm update cordova
```

but nothings change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm uninstall cordova -g`

`npm install cordova@9.0.0 -g`

-g is for global